# ffmpeg to make mp4 container with opus audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp4, opus

I have audio in opus format and need to make mp4 container

```
ffmpeg -i input.opus -c:a opus -strict experimental output.mp4
```

Throws `Could not find tag for codec opus in stream`

What is wrong here?

Comment: @oguzismail, it's interesting, but seems like mp4 can: https://opus-codec.org/docs/opus_in_isobmff.html

Comment: You'll need version 3.4 or newer. Brand option not needed.

Comment: @Gyan, big thanks for this.